# Firebase Authentication Template > Password Reset > getting html tags as it is, not html formatted content

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have 2 firebase project, working separately.  I have modified password reset templates in both few week back.  I noticed now, one is sending mail with proper html formatted content, while other sending html tag as it is.

I copied 1st template to 2nd project still 2nd one sending html content as it is.

appreciated if someone can help me. (I am using my own SMTP in both).

1st project sends like -
`Hello Deepak,`

2nd project sends like -
`<p>Hello Deepak,</p>`

though template looks like -
`<p>Hello %DISPLAY_NAME%,</p>`

Answer (score 3):

I contacted Firebase's support team about this issue and they pointed out a [config that can be set through a REST API call](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects/updateConfig) that sets Firebase emails to send as HTML. [Here's a script that shows how this can be used](https://gist.github.com/torresalmonte/f1c10e22bc8ac282febdb49ed7d7a438).

After making that call and updating Firebase's SMTP settings to send through a 3rd party service, my emails were no longer being sent only as plain text.

Comment: Very helpful! Worked like a charm using a local copy of my service account credentials

Answer (score 1):

**FIREBASE/MAILGUN HTML SETTINGS**

I've finally worked it out and hope it can help somebody:

1. Go to https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground
2. Under "Step 1", select "**Firebase Dynamic Links API v1**" as the scope
3. Click "**Authorize APIs**" and log into the Google Account assocaited with your Firebase App
4. Under "Step 2", click "**Exchange authorization code for tokens**"
5. Under "Step 3", change HTTP method to **PATCH**
6. Enter the Request URI `https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/admin/v2/projects/*{FIREBASE_PRODJECT_ID}*/config?updateMask=notification.sendEmail.resetPasswordTemplate.bodyFormat` (Add your project ID in there!)
7. Click "**Enter request body**" and input `{notification:{sendEmail:{resetPasswordTemplate:{bodyFormat: "HTML"}}}}` and click "Close" at the bottom.
8. Click "**Send the request**"

If you get `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` within the response, job done.
You can now send HTML emails using Firebase using Mailgun!

Comment: This is really helpful. Thanks @JackMcLaughlin
I am not sure about Mailhgun use here as I am using custom SMTP settings in my project. 
However this utility provided helps sending HTML contents over email body while using custom SMTP in Firebase.